# Javascript and Firebase Error "This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol""

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to write a pure javascript web app with firebase login through google auth, when I setup the auth in javascript I get the error "This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.". I am not sure what do to.

Here is my code (I removed my id's and whatnot):

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "MY KEY",
            authDomain: "MY DOMAIN",
            databaseURLMY URL",
            projectId: "MY ID",
            storageBucket: "MY BUCKET",
            messagingSenderId: "MY ID"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);


        function login() {
            function newLoginHappened(user) {
                if (user) {
                    //User is signed in
                    app(user);
                } else {
                    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
                    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
                }
            }

            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(newLoginHappened);
        }

        function app() {
            document.getElementById("clientName").innerHTML = user.displayName;
        }

        window.onload = login;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you cannot run the file by just double clicking the html fine and opening it in browser. You need to run the file through a server.

Comment: Good solution. On Firebase, the easiest way to run it on a server is using the `firebase serve` command.

Comment: how we can run html file through server using expressJs ? please explain with some code example.