# How to fix "This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" ..." error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to use Firebase (Google) authentication but I'm getting this error:

> This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.

My code is:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();  

function Singin(){
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    var user = result.user;
    console.log(user);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(error.message)
  });
}
```

The full error is:

```
zi {code: "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment", message: "This operation is not supported in the environment…chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled."}
code: "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment"
message: "This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled."
__proto__: Error
```

Comment: So you are loading from file:// ? That would explain it

Comment: Yes I do. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes. As it says.

Comment: And how can I fix it?

Comment: Run from a server

Comment: I don't have a server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript and Firebase Error "This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059919/javascript-and-firebase-error-this-operation-is-not-supported-in-the-environmen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot run client-side JS with NodeJS, where `location.protocol` might likely be `typeof "undefined"`. You're using the wrong one client library for the environment; try [the other one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebaseauth). JavaScript and JavaScript are not necessarily the same thing ...

Comment: This doesnt sound right to me. Everything was working fine until. I updated NPM. With respect, try the other one is not a good answer. I dont know what the right answer would be but this isnt it. IMO.

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this? Getting the same error running a Ionic Capacitor app via Xcode iPhone 13 simulator.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your project locally, you can fix this issue by spinning up a local server instead of directly opening the file in your browser. that's how I fixed mine.

Comment: Useful to add how to [Spinning Up A Local Server | Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/article/spinning-up-a-local-server)

Answer (score -4):

I faced this error too.
I fixed it by hosting my project online

Comment: This answer does not solve the issue, particularly for people who want to run a project locally during development before deploying to a live server.