# How to support HTTP protocol in Electron/Firebase App

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

I'm trying to user firebase authentication (saml) within my Electron app. I have read that Electron isn't "officially supported", however I've also encountered some threads that indicate people have gotten it to work. My issue is when using `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect` (or `signInWithPopup`), I get the error:

```
 code: "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment"
 message: "This operation is not supported in the environment this application
 is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and 
 web storage must be enabled."
```

Google turns up [this tips and tricks article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/using-firebase-in-electron-tips-and-tricks-24ac5b44bf5a) which suggests just using a hosted URL:

> Third, OAuth requests need to have a verifiable origin, which can be whitelisted in the Firebase Console. This requires the current Electron browser window to use the http or https protocol, and not file. That means the current window contents should be loaded with browserWindow.loadURL and not browserWindow.loadFile, and the url must be an http or https url, not a file:// url. This generally requires a hosted page somewhere that gets wrapped into the Electron window.

This will probably work, as just running the app locally on the angular dev server works by simply using:

```
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:4200');
```

I don't want to do this because having a hosted page lessens much of the appeal of having a native app.

I could make this work in by just having a local Node/Express instance serve the app locally using [get-port](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-port) to find a free port to run the app there. I haven't really seen any examples showing this. There are a few Stackoverflow questions on getting it to work, but nothing that makes me think it is an acceptable production-level solution.

#### Is a local Express server an acceptable way to circumvent this error, or is there currently a better solution?

Note: [The package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebaseauth) recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57511205/1252748) is not published by Firebase and anyway doesn't look like it supports SAML auth.

Comment: I think using a server is the way to go. But if you don't like that option, you could try setting `location.protocol` manually on your page using `location.protocol = 'http:'`. Not sure if this works, since I've never done it before. But it's worth a try

Comment: Its a security restriction to not allow file:// and any other method against SAML policy. Circumvent it is nearly impossible. If you even did it, its a security flaw that eventually will be fixed in future.. so why risk?. Prudent way is to host a server component that does SAML mechanism for your client.

Comment: @Nirus so just to be clear, you support the local node server idea? Fyi i do the saml auth on the client side with angular-firebase; it doesn’t happen on the node server.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something very similar but with Auth0 instead of Firebase.

What I had to do was make two Browser Windows, where the first one is strictly an authentication Browser Window while the second one is the actual main App Browser Window.

Auth0 has the same restrictions of whitelisting only http/s protocols, so in the authentication Browser window, I load the Auth0 sign in URL via localhost (it’s a hosted URL in Auth0 itself). I then take the credentials (access token and refresh token) from that redirect/Oauth process and store them locally for the time being (use Keytar, SafeStorage, FS modules, whatever; I chose Keytar).

Then my authentication Browser Window closes itself and launches the main, app Browser Window.

From here onward, I have to reference my stored access token and refresh tokens from my storage location and use those in all other calls.

So, for instance, I have some API library modules I made for myself that use Axios. So I bring the saved access token into all of my Axios calls. Works like a charm.

So, in summary: I had to use two different Browser Windows and persist credentials locally for later use in the main Browser Window.

Check out Auth0’s guide on using Electron for authentication; I think you’ll find that many concepts carry over for Firebase and other providers.

Comment: What does it mean you load the auth0 sign in url using localhost?

Comment: @RaghvendraSingh See https://auth0.com/blog/securing-electron-applications-with-openid-connect-and-oauth-2/#Authenticate-Users-in-Electron for an example.

Answer (score -1):

i've successfuly implemented firebase email ver in my app, it is more feasible to load .html file rather than load a page from url as users can exploit the the url by sending fake data. but with oauth it is not possible,firebase create webapp you can create a html file it should contain api keys, host url etc and host it locally in android file://android_assets/filename.html this works fine even offline i dont know properly about 
electron